# How to count the number of a large collection in FireStore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

We have a collection that may contain hundreds of billions of data.
Now we want to get the count of it.

Thanks!

When I'm using `count()` to count the number:

```
ref = db.collection('my_collection').count()
print(ref.get())
```

it always returns error like this:

```
raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Aggregation query timed out. Please try either limiting the entities scanned, or running with an updated index configuration.
```

It's timeout all the time. Am I missing something? What's the proper way to count a large collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have in a single collection, hundreds of billions of documents, then `count()` doesn't seem to be the right solution. If the `count()` function cannot return a result within 60 seconds, then a `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error is thrown. Please note that the performance always depends on the size of the collection. So a possible workaround is to use [counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) for such large collections. Alternatively, you can create and maintain your own counter as explained in this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-firestore-collection-3bd0c719978f).

Comment: Hey May. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thanks Alex, I think that may be helpful!